# Aligning buttons next to many inputs inside a row

Tags: html, css

This is part of a bigger table. I have three fields and each one should have a remove button aligned next to it.

The CSS I have alignes only the first button, and the other buttons are in the same position. How can I place the other two buttons next to their fields.

Thanks!

```css
td .btn.aligned {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 7px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

td input {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a06b1c7829.js"></script>

<table id="tablaProveedores" class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <th>Phone numbers</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="phone1_1" id="telefono1_1" class="form-control" disabled/>
        <a title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs aligned"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>
        <input type="text" name="phone2_1" id="telefono2_1" class="form-control" disabled/>
        <a title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs aligned"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>
        <input type="text" name="phone3_1" id="telefono3_1" class="form-control" disabled/>
        <a title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs aligned"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></a>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a reason all of the inputs need to be in the same row and cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in `<div>`s. Giving them the class `.row` with the bootstrap framework will do everything you need.

```css
td .btn.aligned {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 7px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

td .lowered {
  margin-top: 44px;
}

td input {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.spacer {
  padding-left: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a06b1c7829.js"></script>

<table id="tablaProveedores" class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <th>Phone numbers</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="row">
          <input type="text" name="phone1_1" id="telefono1_1" class="form-control" disabled/>
          <a title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs aligned"><span class="fa fa-times">
          </span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <input type="text" name="phone2_1" id="telefono2_1" class="form-control" disabled/>
          <a title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs aligned"><span class="fa fa-times">
          </span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <input type="text" name="phone3_1" id="telefono3_1" class="form-control" disabled/>
          <a title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs aligned"><span class="fa fa-times">
          </span>
          </a>
        </div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this accomplished with a bit less code. I removed the absolute positioning and applied a max-width to the input and a float left instead of right to the buttons since they're in the same table-cell.
Check out the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1kuL4p4z/)

```
td .btn.aligned {
  margin-top: 7px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

td input {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-width:80%;
}
```